# Split a specific cell in dataframe into a list of values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get cell values from Excel using pandas. In some cases there are multiple values in one cell.

How can I separate them into different values?

[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diw0i.jpg)

---

```
row = str(df_sheet.loc[df_sheet["customer_id"] == customer, "allergies_code"])
customer_allergies = row.values
```

For  `113,115,121` I am getting the output `113115121`.

Comment: How do you want them split? There are two ways: each cell can explode to multiple rows or explode to multiple columns. Unless you want them split into a sub-list, which is again different.

Comment: Define the datatype as string when you load the dataframe, then [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on the comma, and explode if desired.

Comment: thanks for the quick answers. I want to split them into a list. not into rows or multiple columns. how can i define the datatype into a string ? it doesnt work for me